# How to list users without a strong password?

Tags: linux, security, password

I would like to list the username of the users which do not have a strong password in a LAN.
How can I do it?

I do not want to force the password of the users, I want to force the users that have no password or not strong one to change it and use a stronger one.

Comment: I do not wan to force the password of the user.

Comment: Also do look into "Intel vs Randal Schwartz" before getting too deep into password crackers.

Comment: "In a LAN" isn't very specific, but in general passwords are hashed, there's no way to determine if they're "strong" or not without cracking them

Comment: Ok, Thank you @MichaelMrozek for your lights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access to the password database, something like [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) could help you. Though it'd be easier to force a sufficient amount of "strongness" when the users set their passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to talk to John.

http://www.openwall.com/john/

Can be used in conjunction with hydra.